# What are some limitations one can do in terms of using Interwoven Teamsite?

Tags: php, django, wordpress, content-management-system, teamsite

Why would I chose something like Interwoven Teamsite as opposed to Joomla, Django, Wordpress etc. I guess the question is how can one justify the cost associated with a teamsite license. Also by going the teamsite route, do I have any limitations on what can or cannot be modified.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a side-by-side comparison of Joomla and Teamsite: <strike>http://kwebdesign.ca/cms/content/view/106/73/</strike>(dead) http://cmsharbor.com/products/compare/1,6,15/sitecore-cms-vs-joomla-vs-teamsite-autonomy
https://www.google.com/search?q=Joomla+vs+Teamsite

Being as Teamsite's license is proprietary, it's possible that you'd be limited to what you can or can't modify (though I'm guessing here, read their license).

If you're worried about being able to modify the code (for use and/or redistribution) I'd recommend one of the open-source options that have a compatible license (which is most all of them). Actually, I don't see a whole lot on the comparison that would make Teamsite better. The open-source solutions may be a little more work, but they're also a whole lot more flexible. Some of the open-source solutions (e.g. Joomla) have commercial support options. They also have a huge amount of add-on's available -- and they don't cost extra.

When I face a project, I exhaust all available open-source options before debating the paid route. And so far, I haven't had to purchase anything. There is honestly so much good software out there that dedicated, super-talented people put time into, and work as well (if not better) than paid counterparts.

HTH

Comment: The link is dead. Tried to quickly find something comparable, but couldn't find any reliable comparisons.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=Joomla+vs+Teamsite http://cmsharbor.com/products/compare/1,6,15/sitecore-cms-vs-joomla-vs-teamsite-autonomy

Comment: I can google too. CMS Harbor's TeamSite review is outdated as hell so I deemed it not worth linking. Other reviews are of comparable quality.

Comment: Sorry, that's all I got. Maybe download them both and check them out?

Comment: I know TeamSite, just tried to improve a bit on this answer. IMHO it's  impossible to compare both. I could easily install Joomla on my own and tweak it. With teamsite it's another story. It's (really) big, closed-source and targeted for corporations. License prices are also astronomical for mortals so installing it for testing is (almost) impossible.

Comment: Thanks for adding your thoughts. I knew teamsite was proprietary but didn't know it was that bad. Once again, OSS ftw.

Answer (score 2):

Django is a development framework, not an ECM/WCM/CMS like TeamSite, Drupal, and Wordpress.  So it can't really compare (in other words, it can be used to develop something like those other apps with one example being [django-cms](http://www.django-cms.org/)).

As for TeamSite vs. the rest I can only speculate because it's been a long long time since I used TeamSite, but I would guess the workflow features are still hard to beat (maybe [Alfresco](http://www.alfresco.com/) is reasonable equivalent here?) and the integrated version control (also Alfresco might compete here, but not Drupal or Wordpress).  Most PHP based CMS's are going to use MySQL for database which means they're not going to have proper version control.  TeamSite versioning is very nicely done.